# find bits in array of bits

Tags: c#, arrays, bit

there is array of bit and i want to search {00000000000000000000000110110110} in that array

such that:

```
BitArray bitsarr = new BitArray(150);  //array of bits

the bits is {00000000000000000000000110110110} its 32 bits ,i want to
```

search if bits find in array bitsarr or not ,how  can do it using c# language , i do

not need to convert {00000000000000000000000110110110} to hex or ineger or any other type

it must remain bits,only need method to search for bits in bitsarr??

Comment: You really need to clarify this question as it's unclear what you mean by "search bits"

Comment: {00000000000000000000000110110110}this is  a bit i want to search it

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a bit pattern in a bit array using some simple bitwise operations as well. For instance, using XOR on two bits will return 0 if they match and 1 otherwise. You can use the shift operation (<<) to shift the bits left and examine the next bit in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any method for that.

In C# you can use extension method (see [1]) for "add" a public method to an instantiated class.

In that case you can do this:

```
namespace StackOverFlow
{
    static class Program
    {

        public static bool Find(this System.Collections.BitArray text, System.Collections.BitArray pattern)
        {
            //... implement your search algorithm here...
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Collections.BitArray bitsarr = new System.Collections.BitArray(150);

            bool result = bitsarr.Find(new System.Collections.BitArray(new 
bool[]{true, true, false, true}));
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find several matching algorithm on the net, I added two link [2,3] on the bottom of this answer.

For your special case, when the searched string is 32 bit I recommend the Dömölki-(Baeza-Yates)-Gonnet algorithm [4,5,6,7].

Since your possible character set contains 2 elements (0 and 1) this modification may work for you, only and only in the case that you are searching 32bits long patterns.

```
namespace StackOverFlow
{
    static class Program
    {

        public static bool IsFound(this System.Collections.BitArray text, System.Collections.BitArray pattern)
        {
            uint B = 0;
            for (ushort i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
            {
                if (pattern[i])
                {
                    uint num = 1;
                    B |= num << i;
                }
            }
            return IsFound(text, B);
        }

        public static bool IsFound(this System.Collections.BitArray text, uint B)
        {
            uint nB = ~B;
            uint D = 0;
            const uint end = ((uint)1) << 31;
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++ )
            {
                uint uD = (D << 1) + 1;
                D = uD & (text[i] ? B : nB);
                if ((D & end) > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Collections.BitArray bitsarr = new System.Collections.BitArray(150);

            //Tests:
            bitsarr[0] = true;
            bitsarr[1] = true;
            bitsarr[2] = false;
            bitsarr[3] = true;

            bitsarr[50] = true;
            bitsarr[51] = true;
            bitsarr[52] = true;
            bitsarr[53] = false;
            bitsarr[54] = false;
            bool result = bitsarr.IsFound(new System.Collections.BitArray(new bool[]{true, true, false, true}));
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, expected True", result);
            result = bitsarr.IsFound(new System.Collections.BitArray(new bool[] { true, true, true, true }));
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, expected False", result);
            result = bitsarr.IsFound(new System.Collections.BitArray(new bool[] { true, true, true, false }));
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, expected True", result);
            result = bitsarr.IsFound(new System.Collections.BitArray(new bool[] { false, true, true, true }));
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, expected True", result);
            result = bitsarr.IsFound(new System.Collections.BitArray(new bool[] { false, true, true, true }));
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, expected True", result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}
```

Note: further test is required.

(I can not add a link here, since I need 10 reputation)

Comment: links:
[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

[3] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

[4] Dömölki-(Baeza-Yates)-Gonnet algorithm: http://users-cs.au.dk/cstorm/courses/StrAlg_f12/slides/Shift-and-OR.pdf

[5] Bitmap algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm 

[6] Shift-And algorithm http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/opetus/11s/spa/lecture04.pdf

[7] http://users-cs.au.dk/cstorm/courses/StrAlg_f12/slides/Shift-and-OR.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
static bool findbits(BitArray bits, bool[] bitstofind)
  {
    IEnumerator e = bits.GetEnumerator();
    List<bool> bitsc = new List<bool>();
    while (e.MoveNext())
        bitsc.Add((bool)e.Current);
    for (int i = 0; i + bitstofind.Length < bitsc.Count; i++)
        if (bitsc.GetRange(i, bitstofind.Length).ToArray().SequenceEqual(bitstofind)) return true;
    return false;
  }
```

Note 1: 0 is false, 1 is true

Note 2: BitArray must be instantiated using an array of bools(converted or no)